# How do you include a pinvoked dll in a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, pinvoke

I'm making [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PicNet.XGBoost/) NuGet package ([source](https://github.com/PicNet/XGBoost.Net/tree/master/XGBoost)) which pinvokes a dll `libxgboost.dll` (which is built from [XGBoost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html)). However, it's currently throwing an exception because it cannot locate `libxgboost.dll`.

How do I include `libxgboost.dll` into my NuGet package so I can pinvoke it?

**Calling Code (with Package Installed)**

```
using System;
using XGBoost;

namespace TestXGBoostPackage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XGBRegressor r = new XGBRegressor();
            float[][] X = new float[2][];
            X[0] = new float[2];
            X[0][0] = 0;
            X[1] = new float[2];
            X[1][0] = 1;
            float[] y = {0, 1};
            r.Fit(X, y);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception Thrown by Calling Fit()**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in XGBoost.dll

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'libxgboost.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

**DLL Import Statement for Function PInvoked by Fit()**

```
[DllImport("libxgboost.dll")]
public static extern int XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(float[] data, ulong nrow, ulong ncol, 
                                                float missing, out IntPtr handle);
```

**nuspec File for Package**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>PicNet.XGBoost</id>
    <version>0.0.2.1</version>
    <title>XGBoost.Net</title>
    <authors>John Smith</authors>
    <owners>John Smith</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/PicNet/XGBoost.Net</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://www.picnet.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo-dark.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>.Net wrapper for the XGBoost machine learning library.</description>
    <releaseNotes>test dll dependency fix</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>machine learning xgboost boosted tree</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

In the package's project properties, the build output path is `bin\Debug\` and the platform target is `x64`.

Answer (score 1):

You might pack a native NuGet package for the native library,

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/native-packages

And then your managed NuGet package can depend on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean I need to make a native NuGet package out of the original [XGBoost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) c++ code and then refer to that in my NuGet package? Does that mean I have to pinvoke differently or use something different from pinvoke?